# How to generate a Subgroup thru coset representative/group element pairs

Tags: group-theory

My main priority is to understand what the question is asking (how the different concepts relate). Secondarily, any hints along the way would be helpful...

Set: K a group.
Set: L a subgroup.
Set: P a set of right coset representatives (w/ e∈P).
Therefore, we have a bijection: P×L → K given by (p,l)↦pl.
Define w(k,p)∈P and z(k,p)∈L by the requirement that kp=w(k,p)z(k,p), for all k∈K, p∈P. Let G be a set of generators of K.
Show that the set of {z(g,p)} where g∈G and p∈P generates L.

Comment: I did not bold anything. I believe the title is bolded automatically.

Comment: It's probably a good idea to do this with an actual group so you can see what is happening in the question.

Comment: That's a good idea, I'll try it.

Comment: All right, I've shown that ∀g∈G we have gPL′⊂PL′ (where L' is a subgroup of L generated by {z(g,p)}), but I'm now having trouble showing that ∀k∈K we have gPL′⊂PL′.

Comment: What do you mean by PL'? Do you mean all products of the form $pl'$ where $p\in P$ and $l' \in L'$? If so, I'm not sure that $gPL' \subset PL'$ really says anything. Also, are you sure that the bijection is $P\times L \to K$? Since we are talking about right cosets it would seem $L\times P \to K$ is the right thing to use? But then everything would be around the other way (e.g. the w and z should swap also).